Prove that in a Euclidean Domain $R$, a least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is $\frac{ab}{\gcd(a, b)}$.
Prove that in a Euclidean Domain $R$, a least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is $\frac{ab}{\gcd(a, b)}$.
My attempt: Let $c = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a, b)}$. Obviously, since $\frac{b}{\gcd(a, b)}$ and $\frac{a}{\gcd(a, b)}$ are elements of $R$, $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$. Now what I need to show is $\forall e \in R$, if $a \mid e$
and $b \mid e$, then $c \mid e$. Suppose $a \mid e$ and $b \mid e$. Since $R$ is a Euclidean domain with a Euclidean function, say $\varphi$, and $c \neq 0$, $$e = cq + r \text{ for some } q, r \in R \text{ such that } r = 0 \text{ or } \varphi(r) < \varphi(c).$$ Now, I need to show that we cannot have $\varphi(r) < \varphi(c)$, and therefore $r = 0$. But this is where I am stuck; I don't know why $\varphi(r) < \varphi(c)$ is impossible.

Please search for answers before posting questions. $\ \ $

I search. But your understanding of duplicate is not the same as mine. Probably you are an advanced mathematician and this allows you to see everything as one. @Bill

Please delete this duplicate - we already have too many proofs of this basic result.

I rest my case.

Here is a solution I found:
$$
\text{Let }d = \gcd(a,b).\;\text{Then }d\mid a\;\text{and}\;d\mid b.
\;\text{Hence}\;\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d}\in R.
$$
$$
\text{Define }c := \frac{ab}{d}.\;
\text{Notice that }c = a\cdot\frac{b}{d} = b\cdot\frac{a}{d}, 
\text{ so }a\mid c\;\text{and}\;b\mid c.
$$
$$
\text{Next, let }e\in R\;\text{such that}\;a\mid e\;\text{and}\;b\mid e.
\;\text{Then }e = ax = by\;\text{for some }x,y\in R.
$$
$$
\text{Since }a = dt\;\text{and }b = ds\;\text{for some }t,s \in R,\;
\text{we have }e = dtx = dsy\;\Longrightarrow t\,x = s\,y.
$$
$$
\text{Also, }c = \frac{ab}{d} = \frac{d\,t \cdot d\,s}{d} = d\,t\,s.
$$
$$
\text{Because }a = d\,t,\;b = d\,s,\;\text{and }d = \gcd(a,b),
\;\text{it follows that }\gcd(t,s) = 1\;
(\text{otherwise }d\;\text{would not be the gcd}).
$$
$$
\text{Hence there exist }m,n \in R\;\text{with }1 = t\,m + s\,n. \text{(Because R is a E.D.)}
$$
$$
\text{We deduce }x = t\,x\,m + s\,x\,n
\;\Longrightarrow s\mid x
\;\Bigl(\text{because }s\mid \bigl(t\,x\,m + s\,x\,n\bigr)\Bigr).
$$
$$
\text{So }x = s\,k\;\text{for some }k \in R.\;
\text{Thus }e = d\,t\,x = d\,t\,s\,k.
$$
$$
\text{But }c = d\,t\,s.\;\text{So }c\mid e.
\;\text{Therefore, }c\;\text{is a least common multiple of }a\text{ and }b.
$$

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

If you found the proof somewhere, you should cite the source.

I don't think my question is a dupe. My question is about any Euclidean Domains and the suggested dupes are just for integers. Also, they are not very similar to my question. I did not find the answer from SE by the way. I was just trying to help others; I could have deleted the post as soon as I found an answer. @Bill

The solution I found is due to "a collaboration of ChatGPT and me". I am not sure how I should cite this. @Gonçalo

The dupes include proofs that work in any gcd domain - so any Euclidean domain. Your proof is the mentioned (less general) Bezout-form of the one-line proof in this answer. $\ \ $
